# Intel sound card, internal microphone not recognized by linux kernel

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, kernel, microphone

I have opensuse with the kernel 5.3.18 running on Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 5.
I experience problems configuring sound card *Intel Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS*. More specifically, builtin microphone is not recognized. Configuring sound using yast2-gui results in the message

> The kernel module snd-soc-skl for sound support
> could not be loaded. This can be caused by incorrect
> module parameters, including invalid IO or IRQ parameters.

`lspci -vv` output

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS (prog-if 80)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 22be
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 64
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 141
        Region 0: Memory at ea33c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Region 4: Memory at ea000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee004b8  Data: 0000
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev
```

Hardware profile is at https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=e40b11dca2.

Any help in configuring the device is appreciated.